# Is this possible to get dynamic dropdown's selected value before SelectedIndexChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a set of tables, dropdowns, buttons, labels **dynamically** on **OnInit()** event on the basis of list of objects( fetched from database). I have bound events with these dynamic controls as well.

On **dropdowns_SelectedIndexChanged** event I have to populate my list of objects again from database on the basis of selected value and **recreate** these tables, labels again.

First time dropdown selection is working fine for me, but as soon as I am recreating control here on **dropdowns_SelectedIndexChanged**, the event of dropdowns are not bound (as it is compulsory to add dynamic controls on OnInit() to bound events with them) .

Now for an alternative I am trying to get dropdown's selected value on any Page event near by **pre_render()** so that I could recreate my controls there with updated objects List without any **dropdowns_SelectedIndexChanged** event.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is one nasty way!

You can index the Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] that should get you what your after.

BUT I wouldn't necessarily/always recommend it.  Even when adding controls dynamically you should be able to get the selected value, in the correct event handler.   It's probably owing to where you are adding the control in the page lifecycle.

Comment: Hi @brumScouse, I have used the following code on page_Init()

Control control = null;
string controlName = page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];

   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controlName))
    {
     control = page.FindControl(controlName);
      if (control is DropDownList)
        {
           string selectedValue = ((DropDownList)control).SelectedValue;
        }
             
     }

but its still not giving me the latest selected value as soon as it reaches on page_init() after selection of any value of dropdown.

Comment: Can you give me all of your code maybe in an email?